# Como usar o Scheduler no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Estou seguindo a documentação do laravel para criar uma Scheduler, porem estou tento dificuldade. Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Nesse comando:

```
php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

entendo que o `path-to-your-project` seria o caminho do meu projeto, em outras palavras, eu poderia entrar na pasta do projeto e executar apenas o `php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`, certo?

Porem o terminal informa que o caminho não existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O caminho do meu projeto é `c:\projetos\marcelo\painel` e inclusive é onde se encontra o arquivo do artisan.

Comment: Eu creio que seja o direcionamento para `/dev/null` o problema. Tente não direcionar para canto algum. O caminho nulo usado é um padrão no mundo Unix, não no Windows.

Comment: Qual a versão do laravel?

Comment: Consegui resolver removendo o caminho e deixando até o comando 'run'. 
Valeu pessoal!
O laravel q uso é o 5.3